# error while building the app , since astro dynamic pages has some issues while building app

Tags: javascript, blogs, astrojs

```
 error   Expected "tag" to match ".*", but got "----optimization
  ----performance
  ----lottie
  ----react
  ----animation
  ----adobe-after-effects"
  File:
    /Users/karthikeyan/Documents/incresecoCode/incresco-astro/node_modules/path-to-regexp/dist/index.js:229:27
  Code:
    228 |                 if (validate && !matches[i].test(segment)) {
    > 229 |                     throw new TypeError("Expected \"".concat(token.name, "\" to match \"").concat(token.pattern, "\", but got \"").concat(segment, "\""));
          |                           ^
      230 |                 }
      231 |                 path += token.prefix + segment + token.suffix;
      232 |                 continue;
```

I was expecting a successful build, but it failed due to some issues with the package `path-to-regexp` from `astro`, that tag is a slug in the dynamic routes in `astro` app